# Can't access specific files in Windows

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

I'm trying to view a PDF file in Windows, but my access to it is denied for some reason. It's in a folder that I have full permissions for (also set to apply to subfolders and files), and I can access other files in the same folder (and manipulate their security tab). For the file that I can't access, it doesn't even show the security tab. I've gone through the standard Group Policy and regedit fixes for a missing security tab, but I still can't access the file or its permissions. I've also made sure to take ownership of the folder. The only unusual property the file has is that the location is prepended with '\?', but other files in the directory also have this prepended and I can still open them.

tldr:

- Can't access some files in some folders
- All of the afflicted files are on a shared drive. Other users on the shared drive can access the files, even with identical permissions
- Some files in the folders can be accessed, some cannot
- Seemingly no pattern to filetype or extension and not functioning
- I have full read/write permissions to folder, subfolders, and files
- Can't view security tab on these denied files
- Group Policy and regedit fixes haven't worked

If I copy and paste the file, I can open the copy. If I copy the folder somewhere else, I can open the copy of the file in the copied folder. But, if I copy the folder, delete the original folder, and replace it with the copy, I still can't access the file. They're also personal files, primarily PDFs, .txt, and json files.

I'm at the end of my rope here, any ideas? I'm guessing it's a corrupted user profile/account, but would prefer to only modify account info as a last resort.

Comment: This is likely a stupid question, but there are several types of errors, many users misdiagnose as a permission problem.  Can you provide a screenshot of the exact error you received? You can remove any information that can identfy you, the filename, isn't the important part provided the error is in English.

Comment: @Ramhound Adobe acrobat gives the error "There was an error opening this document. Access denied". Attempting to open the PDF in Chrome gives the message "Your file couldn’t be accessed It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". PDFInfo.exe return "I/O Error: Couldn't open file". The main reason why I think it's a weird permissions issue or corrupted profile is that other users on the shared drive can access these files.

Comment: Some Windows folders are very highly secured. Are you trying to store in such locations?

Comment: @John Nope, and even then, you'd expect ALL of the files in a folder to be locked if it was secured against my permissions level

Comment: I see no mention of you running `chkdsk` on said volume.  A corrupt profile will not cause this sort of problem but a corrupt file system could.  Perhaps I missed that part somewhere in your post.  To be fair.. this is indeed an odd one :P

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Just ran chkdsk and it found no problems. This is a very interesting issue that I've never seen before, and I haven't been able to find anything similar online.

Comment: @SlamJammington - Can you give us any indication of the root directory for the folder containing the file? According to my research, `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` is an error Chrome throws when the file cannot be found. Chrome has a separate error that handles file permission errors. My first instinct is security software, mainly because I had to troubleshoot an individual's "Access Denied" message in a command prompt and diagnosed it to security software active on the machine just yesterday.

Comment: @Ramhound "D:\Share\privateArchive\US States\private\private \private\private\Documents\Development Services\Community Development Department\Planning\private\A-2022-0034 - private private for private @ 508 privateprivate. - DES, CZC\Approved" is the drive itself, S:\ is the network share that is created based on D:\Share. I cannot open the file from either location, but on a different machine I can open the file. Both are running BitDefender so I might look into that

Comment: @SlamJammington - The length of the path is sort of long.  If you copy the file to a different folder several folders down the path, can you open the file? Windows has a 255 character limit on paths, including the filename and extension of the file itself. This limit would seemingly apply to Chrome and Adobe Acrobat at the very least. The string you submitted is 230 characters.  So if your filename, longer than 11 characters, you have exceeded the 255 character limit.

Comment: @Ramhound Yep, they're going over the 255 character limit. The files were created and named programmatically, so there wasn't any check to verify the path's length. Solved, thank you!

Comment: @SlamJammington - You should check for the length of the path by using a method that checks the length of the string before creating the folder. I mean, the path had the word "private" 7 times. I am guessing the file is meant to be submitted to the public. Thats a joke...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the filepath was too long, so some files in the folder were going over the 255 character path limit, while others were under the limit. They were being created and named programmatically, and there wasn't any checks regarding filepath length. Thanks @Ramhound!

Comment: Give credit to @ramhound for solving it.